Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details
I have this issue after installing "react-native-reanimated": "^3.12.0". When I try building the project, I get the error below.
enter codeDeprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
157 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 155 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

/Users/olabanjoolakunori/Documents/PersonalReactNativeProjects/Plant_Brunch/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/reactNativeVersionPatch/ReactHost/72/com/swmansion/reanimated/DevMenuUtils.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    private void addDevMenuOption(ReactApplicationContext context, DevOptionHandler handler) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class DevMenuUtils
/Users/olabanjoolakunori/Documents/PersonalReactNativeProjects/Plant_Brunch/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/reactNativeVersionPatch/ReactHost/72/com/swmansion/reanimated/DevMenuUtils.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    private void addDevMenuOption(ReactApplicationContext context, DevOptionHandler handler) {
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class DevOptionHandler
  location: class DevMenuUtils
/Users/olabanjoolakunori/Documents/PersonalReactNativeProjects/Plant_Brunch/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/nativeProxy/NativeProxyCommon.java:85: error: addDevMenuOption(ReactApplicationContext,DevOptionHandler) has private access in DevMenuUtils
    DevMenuUtils.addDevMenuOption(mContext.get(), this::toggleSlowAnimations);
                ^
/Users/olabanjoolakunori/Documents/PersonalReactNativeProjects/Plant_Brunch/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/reactNativeVersionPatch/ReactHost/72/com/swmansion/reanimated/DevMenuUtils.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    if (context.getApplicationContext() instanceof ReactApplication) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: class DevMenuUtils
/Users/olabanjoolakunori/Documents/PersonalReactNativeProjects/Plant_Brunch/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/reactNativeVersionPatch/ReactHost/72/com/swmansion/reanimated/DevMenuUtils.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
      final DevSupportManager devSupportManager =
            ^
  symbol:   class DevSupportManager
  location: class DevMenuUtils
/Users/olabanjoolakunori/Documents/PersonalReactNativeProjects/Plant_Brunch/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/reactNativeVersionPatch/ReactHost/72/com/swmansion/reanimated/DevMenuUtils.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
          ((ReactApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
            ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: class DevMenuUtils
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s here

I tried adding the code below to my build.gradle in my android, as suggested by facebook in a github issues post from 2022, but it still did not work.
allprojects {
    repositories { /* ... */ }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.72.7'
        }
    }
}

Other info:
"react-native": "0.72.7",
react native doctor:
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ Ruby - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✖ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment


This strangely, was a version issue that made the app crash while trying to build. To fix this do the below;

Uninstall the previous reanimated package.
cd to android and clean your gradle - cd android && ./gradlew clean
As of today, use the rc release: "react-native-reanimated": "^3.9.0-rc.1" by running npm install react-native-reanimated@3.9.0-rc.1
Run your project with npx react-native start --reset-cache to clean your cache.

